# Error referencing angular component from a component in another module

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am working in an Angular system, adding a new component to a module ('Cards') that already contains several other components. My code runs locally, but I'm getting an error when I try to build it.

My new component needs to use some functionality from another component in a separate module (let's call it 'widget'), so I have added the angular tag for that component to the html template in my new component. I have also imported the module in the NGModule imports.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
cards   (the module being worked on)
 + existing-card-1
 + existing-card-2
 + new-card
    + new-card.component.html
    + new-card.component.scss
    + new-card.component.spec.ts
    + new-card.component.ts
 cards.module.ts
 index.ts
widget
 widget.component.html
 widget.component.scss
 widget.component.spec.ts
 widget.component.ts
 widget.module.ts
 index.ts
```

The widget component is already in use in a similar way in several other modules.

I have tried to use the widget component within the new-card component as follows:

new-card.component.html looks like this (stripped down):

```
<div class='new-card'>
  <widget [title]='content.title'>
  </widget>
</div>
```

In order to use the `<widget>` tag, I've imported WidgetModule into the main Cards.module.ts as follows:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ExistingCard1Component } from "./existing-card-1/existing-card-1.component";
import { ExistingCard2Component } from "./existing-card-2/existing-card-2.component";
import { NewCardComponent } from "./new-card/new-card.component";
import { WidgetModule } from "../widget/widget.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    WidgetModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ExistingCard1Component,
    ExistingCard2Component,
    NewCardComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ExistingCard1Component,
    ExistingCard2Component,
    NewCardComponent,
  ],
})
export class CardsModule {}
```

As far as I understand it, this should be enough to allow `<widget>` to be used in new-card.component.html. And true enough, when I run it locally and test it in a browser, it works.

However, when I build it using `ng build --prod`, it throws the following errors:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'CardsModule in /Users/me/projects/our-system/dist/our-system/our-system.d.ts'
Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'CardsModule in /Users/me/projects/our-system/dist/our-system/our-system.d.ts'
'widget' is not a known element:
1. If 'widget' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'widget' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div class="new-card">
  [ERROR ->]<widget [title]="content.title">
")
```

I've tried a bunch of combinations of importing and exporting the Widget module and component into CardsModule, but nothing has resolved the error above (a few things I've tried have added to it though).

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, please? I'm pretty new to Angular, but this seems like a pretty standard thing, so I'm obviously doing something daft.

Comment: Have you exported widgetcomponent from widgetmodule?

Comment: @harpal - yes, WidgetModule includes an export of WidgetComponent. I haven't touched the widget module or component; as I said, they already work correctly in use elsewhere in other modules.

Comment: You should post the widget module. Also, are you sure the widget component's selector is not <app-widget>?

Comment: Check the selector as @LucasMoreira mention and What is in index.ts, is it to expose module publically? ,if so, then check imported path for WidgetModule.

Comment: As you might know, when an unknown element is referenced, you get an error from NGTSC (whatever that is) telling you so. Maybe it really is an unknown element and there is something wrong with your linter. I would at least restart the IDE. NGTSC apparently is embedded in the Angular packages. Their description of the error that normally appears: https://angular.io/errors/NG8001

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. @LucasMoreira, yes in fact it is prefixed; I substitued the actual name for 'widget' in the question to anonymise it, but I have used the full prefixed selector in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.

It turned out that I had got everything right in the code after all. The problem was that I was missing a step when rebuilding it, and thus the build step I was doing was still picking up the problem even after it was fixed.

Short anwswer: I needed to do a `yarn build` every time as well as `ng build`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I cannot comment so I have to make an actual answer.

Regarding your own answer, know that you have a `.angular` folder at the root of your project : this is used by the CLI to speed up the compilation of your project.

Sometimes it keeps the errors as you have faced : just removing this folder and re-running `ng serve` or `ng build` shoudl do the trick.

Hope this helps the next time you face a similar issue !